# How does Nginx pick a site to serve on an instance with 2 sites?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, virtualhost

I replicated an EC2 instance on AWS because the owner lost the pem file and couldn't SSH in. It has two sites configured, but when I access this server via its public DNS, it serves me one of the sites. How does it know to pick the site it serves me? I don't see any configuration that would indicate one of the sites is the default one (something like `listen 80 default`).

In `/etc/nginx/sites-available` (in order):

```
default
new-site
site
```

In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` (in order):

```
new-site
site
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are browsing to a proper hostname, your browser will send a `Host` header to the server. Then, if there's a matching vhost (look at the `server_name` directives), nginx will serve that vhost.

If you're browsing to the server IP *or* if you are browsing to a hostname that does not match any of the `server_name` directives, it will serve the default vhost or whichever vhost file it loaded first (by alpha order).

Note: if these are HTTPS connections, [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) is also involved.

Comment: I was accessing it via `http://ec2-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`. It doesn't match any `server_name`s, so alphabetical order I take it.

Comment: @musicliftsme Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Its only looking at `sites-avaliable` it seems? The `default` config has `server_name localhost` which seems like it won't do anything in terms of serving pages to the browser from the outside.

Comment: sites-enabled are the active sites.